# What is 'draft slides"?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

The following was part of a conference announcement.

> Submit **draft slides** to apply for the conference.

What is *draft slides*? Is it the same as *presentation slides*? Is it the same as *powerpoint slides*? As the word 'draft' implies, does 'draft slides' means just a few most important slides, or a preliminary version of presentation slides?

I couldn't find a definition for the term 'draft slides' on the internet.

Comment: You might try looking words up separately. draft is a verb and an adjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Draft" means the opposite to "final version".  When you are creating any kind of document you might create a "draft", and then edit it and improve it until you have the final version.

Slides are likely to be PowerPoint, but could be Google docs or "prezi" or even pdf. (In the past they could also be actual piece of plastic that you would "slide" onto a projector). The are a document that will be displayed on a projector, usually as a way of making a lecture more interesting.

So this is asking you to submit the PowerPoint file (or whatever system you are using) But you are not expected to have the final version yet. The preliminary, slightly rough, not completely edited, "draft version" of your slides is fine.

You should submit all the slides you have for the presentation, not a sample. You may add additional slides later, or remove some for the final version. But this is not asking for just the most important slides.

Answer (score 1):

Just look for 'draft'. A draft slide, article, essay, plan, etc, is an early or preliminary version.

> A draft plan, document, etc. is in its first form, including the main
>   points but not all the details:
>
> a draft plan/bill/proposal

[Draft (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/draft)